# Should I encapsulate id field with my own type?

Tags: types, language-agnostic

Considering below snippets:

```
class User {
  String id;

  ...other fields
}
```

```
class Id extends String {

}

class User {
  Id id;

  ...other fields
}
```

Which one should I use? I've never seen anoyone using their own Id type. Now I'm thinking: are there any drawbacks to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This technique is called *microtyping*, sometimes *tiny typing*. It tends to make your code more expressive and thus safer and more readable.
However it also creates another layer of indirection: The reader of your code has to learn what an `Id` is to fully understand it. She probably already knows what a `String` is.

Generally I highly recommend microtyping. There are probably cases where it could be overdone but I haven't found one so far. So don't worry.

Concerning your specific implementation: In some languages like Java it is not possible to derive from standard classes like `String`. In other languages like C++ it is possible but not recommended. Therefore I would rather use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class Id {
    private String id;
    ...
}
```